# What is the minimum expected amount in following?

Tags: probability, expected-value, interval-censoring

Suppose X borrowed **$100** from you. Now, there is **0.8 probability** that X will return **>=50%** of the loaned amount and 0.2 probability that <50%  of the amount.

Now, is it right to say that expected minimum amount is :

```
expected minimum amount= (0.8*(50% of $100) + 0.2*0)
```

which will be \$40 according to above formula, shouldn't it be just minimum expected amount is \$50 with 80% probability ?

I've serious doubt in this, how can the probability of getting minimum 50% of the amount(\$50) results in that minimum amount expected is $40 ?

Comment: First of all, for me it is a bit confusing to read the expression "expected minimum". Also, you need to say what happens in the other $20\%$ of cases. However, if in that $20\%$ you have no gain and no loss, your calculation is correct, so your expectation is $40$ $.

Comment: @FedericoTedeschi Hi thanks for your response. 0.8 is the probability of >=50% return and 0.2 is the probability < 50% return.

Comment: Thus you can't calculate an expected value in the worst-case scenario, because you have the worse case in case of return at least $50\%$, but don't have in case of return below $50\%$. Unless you tell me that the probability of loss is $0$: in this case, the worst case in the situation below $50\%$ is $0$ and you could conclude that yes, the expected value is at least $40$ $.

Comment: Maybe 'minimum expected amount' makes more sense than 'expected minimum amount'.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear. Before anything, we should note that the actual minimum possible is 0 which may happen in the 20% branch.

There are two distributions at work here:

1. Which branch you follow
2. What is paid in each branch

The only way I understand the problem would be asking for the mean value assuming question 2 is always answered with a minimum payment. Once you assume stochasticity in question 2, it must be phrased as probability of getting less than X, since we KNOW what the minimum payment is for each branch: 0 and 50 respectively. In the case where we don't know the true lower end of a distribution from which we have samples is when we can start talking about the distribution of a minimum based on observations.

That being said, given the two branches, there is a 20% chance of getting a minimum of 0 and an 80% chance of getting a minimum of 50, so **if** one knows one will be receiving a minimal payout **then** the expected value of that payout is $40. That is not the expected payout over all possibilities---that depends on the distribution of payments in the above question 2. It is also not the minimum possible amount, that is clearly 0.

Comment: A natural way of understanding the question, as suggested in a comment, is "among all the possible probability distributions consistent with the information given, what it the infimum of their expectations?"

Comment: Of course, that requires some distribution of how much will be returned given the branch (call that severity), which is not very clear from the question either. A possible distribution in the severity universe consistent with the question is "pay the minimum each time" which would be less than or equal to any other expected payment value, and would be the mentioned $40, would it not?

Comment: Yes: and that makes this a straightforward question with a simple answer.